# MVC Razor conditional code causing error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in a Razor view where I want to only display an address if the first piece is available.

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Address1))
{
    @Model.Address1<br />
    @Model.Address2<br />
    @Model.City, @Model.State @Model.Zip
}
```

However, it's giving me a design time error saying "Can not use local variable 'Model' before it is declared".

I've done some searching on the syntax and as far as I can tell it looks correct but obviously I'm missing something. Can anyone see why this would work?

**UPDATE**

It's a little clunky looking but this is what I ended up with.

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Address1))
{
    @:@Model.Address1<br />
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Address2))
    {
        @:@Model.Address2<br />
    }                            
    @:@Model.City, @Model.State @Model.Zip
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing HTML which is being parsed as C# code, with confusing results.

The contents of a code block (such as `@if`) are parsed as code, not HTML.

Therefore, `@Model.City, @Model.State @Model.Zip` becomes a malformed variable declaration.

You need to wrap it in an HTML tag or `<text>`, or prefix each line with `@:`.